# kendo grid with virtual scrolling, stuck at page 1

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid with virtual scrolling, with the following angular JS code in the controller:-

```
$scope.options = {
       dataSource: {
               type: "json",
               serverPaging: true,
               pageSize: 100,
               transport: {
                     read: "/rest/error/grid",
                     dataType :"json"
               },
       schema:{data:"data",total:"total"}
       },
       height: 543,
       scrollable: {
             virtual: true
       }
};
```

The json output of my **service** is :

```
{data :[{name:"name0",age:0},
        {name:"name1",age:1},
        ....,
        {name:"name1000",age:1000}
       ],
 total:1000
}
```

The kendo Grid initialized on the UI has:-

```
<div>
<div  kendo-grid="grid" k-options="options" k-rebind="options"></div>
</div>
```

However facing a issue like once i reach 99 record, the call to get next 100 records is made.

However after that second request to get first 100 record also triggered and grid reset to first record.

In effect **unable to scroll beyond page 1(or beyond 100 records)**.

Any ideas to resolve the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the issue, 
The grid works fine when i removed '**k-rebind**' from the html.

It seems the k-bind trigger a rebind action, since data in the options is changed during the scrolling. Thus initializing the grid each time.

Thanks all